# C# library to replace text or fill form field is a PDF

Tags: open-source, library, pdf, c#

What libraries exist to replace text in a PDF or fill PDF form field? I am looking for something free and cannot use iTextSharp's free version due to the licensing requirement to post my source code.

Comment: You're not required to post **your** code when using it. If you modify the library and use it on a server, then you must publish the changes *to the library*, not anything else using the library. Using a GPL library as-is don't means you need to publish everything using it, only changes to it. I could be wrong, but that's a question you could ask on [Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/pdf) can be used to [replace text](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8564/how-to-replace-the-existing-text-in-the-pdf-document) in a PDF or [fill a PDF form field](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5959/how-to-fill-a-pdf-form-template-and-add-it-to-the-new-pdf-document).

[image: Essential PDF Header and Footer]

[Live samples](https://aspdotnetcore.syncfusion.com/PDF/Default#/material) for ASP.NET Core, but the libraries are supported on Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC, WinRT, Windows Phone, Windows store universal and Xamarin applications as well.

VB.NET code is provided for all code samples.

A single license for the File Formats Edition costs $995. The whole product is also available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.